# React Native: Build does not fail on TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-cli

How can I make the React Native CLI fail on a TypeScript error?

```
    const getCatOfTheDay = (cat: string) => `Cat of the day: ${cat}`;
    getCatOfTheDay(123);
```

This should throw a TypeScript error

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

but instead my `npm start` does just continue working and doesn't throw any error.

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "jsx": "react-native",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmit": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "ES2020"
    }
}
```

Using react-native 0.62

Comment: @GuilhermeSantiago Not really. I was reading it up in another place some time ago, but dont remember everything. Most important what I remember is that the build process won't fail for react native, a good approach would be to run type checks in your ci cd pipeines to determine falsy typescript.